# Retrieving a list of facebook user who are checkin at my page location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I want to get all the users who are checkin at specific place i.e the place of my page. For this I have provided user_status,user_checkins,friends_checkins permission to my app:
For this:

```
$listOfusercheckins = $obj_facebook->api("/".$pageId."/checkins", "GET", array("access_token" => $pageAccesstoken));
var_dump($listOfusercheckins);
After var_dump() I always get empty array.
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Some user who have authorize my app have checkin at the location of my page, I need to fetch all those user who are at my page location, How can I fetch all those users? I am both the admin of page and app.

Comment: You can not fetch the checkins for “all users” –  only for the current user of your app and their friends.

Comment: can you please give me the code how can I get the current checkin users of my app, i still gets empty array.. my fql is like this SELECT author_uid  FROM checkin WHERE target_id = 154968791329023